# How to Get Data in Descending order using group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want table records as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | receiver_user_id | sender_user_id | message_text | insertdate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
6  | 33               | 42             | OLD          | 2013-05-08 10:08:53
8  | 33               | 43             | ddddd        | 2013-05-07 19:01:45
7  | 33               | 38             | Ipsum        | 2013-04-25 10:27:35
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM (`player_messages`)
WHERE `receiver_user_id` =  '33'
GROUP BY sender_user_id
ORDER BY `player_messages`.`insertdate` DESC
```

And get table records like below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | receiver_user_id | sender_user_id | message_text | insertdate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
6  | 33               | 43             | ddddd        | 2013-05-07 19:01:45
4  | 33               | 42             | NEW          | 2013-05-07 10:08:58
7  | 33               | 38             | Ipsum        | 2013-04-25 10:27:35
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific? It is not clear what you want to achieve here.

Comment: `ORDER BY insertdate DESC` orders by insert date in descending order, as your example illustrates. You haven't explained why this fails to meet your expectations. Also, your two tables don't belong to the same data set.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75bd5/1)

Comment: GROUP BY is meaningless in this context. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Strawberry: I wouldn't be surprised if the incorrect usage of `group by` kind of messes with the `order by`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are selecting all fields from your table `SELECT *` but you are only grouping by `sender_user_id`, and the values of non-aggregated columns will be untedermined and not affected by an order by.

You should write your query like this:

```
SELECT   player_messages.*
FROM     player_messages
WHERE    (receiver_user_id, sender_user_id, insertdate) IN (
           SELECT   receiver_user_id, sender_user_id, MAX(insertdate)
           FROM     player_messages
           WHERE    receiver_user_id='33'
           GROUP BY receiver_user_id, sender_user_id)
ORDER BY player_messages.insertdate DESC
```

This will return all the rows of player_messages that have the maximum insertdate for every combination of receiver and sender.

Answer (score -3):

When you query your MySQL database, you can sort the results by any field in an ascending or descending order by just adding 'ORDER BY' at the end of your query. You would use **ORDER BY field_name ASC** for an ascending sort, or **ORDER BY field_name DESC** for a descending sort.

eg

```
"SELECT * FROM address ORDER BY name ASC"
```